# Parse dates when YYYYMMDD and HH are in separate columns using pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple question related with csv files and parsing datetime.

I have a csv file that look like this:

```
YYYYMMDD, HH,    X
20110101,  1,   10
20110101,  2,   20
20110101,  3,   30
```

I would like to read it using pandas (read_csv) and have it in a dataframe indexed by the datetime. So far I've tried to implement the following:

```
import pandas as pnd
pnd.read_csv("..\\file.csv",  parse_dates = True, index_col = [0,1])
```

and the result I get is:

```
                         X
YYYYMMDD    HH            
2011-01-01 2012-07-01   10
           2012-07-02   20
           2012-07-03   30
```

As you see the parse_dates in converting the HH into a different date.

Is there a simple and efficient way to combine properly the column "YYYYMMDD" with the column "HH" in order to have something like this? :

```
                      X
Datetime              
2011-01-01 01:00:00  10
2011-01-01 02:00:00  20
2011-01-01 03:00:00  30
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you pass a list to `index_col`, it means you want to create a hierarchical index out of the columns in the list.

In addition, the `parse_dates` keyword can be set to either True or a list/dict. If True, then it tries to parse individual columns as dates, otherwise it combines columns to parse a single date column.

In summary, what you want to do is:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H')
pd.read_csv("..\\file.csv",  parse_dates = [['YYYYMMDD', 'HH']], 
            index_col = 0, 
            date_parser=parse)
```

Comment: What if you start with a dataframe instead as oppose from reading directly in from csv

Comment: A more general solution that starts with a `DataFrame` and need not assume the date is the index column would be really useful.  Perhaps that's a separate question?

Answer (score 11):

I am doing this all the time, so I tested different ways for speed.
The fastest I found is the following, approx. 3 times faster than Chang She's solution, at least in my case, when taking the total time of file parsing and date parsing into account:

First, parse the data file using pd.read_csv withOUT parsing dates. I find that it is slowing down the file-reading quite a lot. Make sure that the columns of the CSV file are now columns in the dataframe df. Then:

```
format = "%Y%m%d %H"
times = pd.to_datetime(df.YYYYMMDD + ' ' + df.HH, format=format)
df.set_index(times, inplace=True)
# and maybe for cleanup
df = df.drop(['YYYYMMDD','HH'], axis=1)
```

Comment: doesn't work, I get `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'`

Comment: I assume you already converted the read-in dates to integers. (Even so in that case my error message looks slightly different: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.dtype' and 'str'. When df.YYYYMMDD and df.HH are strings read-in from a csv file without conversion to integers, this works fine.

Comment: Not aiming for speed, and with data already loaded, I circumvent that issue with, say, `df['year'].astype(int).astype(str)`. Ugly, but works. ;7)