# Getting a time index in python for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, financial, datetimeindex

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the right time index for my pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import strptime
import numpy as np

stockdata = pd.read_csv("/home/stff/symbol_2012-02.csv", parse_dates =[[0,1,2]])
stockdata.columns = ['date_time','ticker','exch','salcond','vol','price','stopstockind','corrind','seqnum','source','trf','symroot','symsuffix']
```

I think the problem is that the time stuff comes in the first three columns: year/month/date, hour/minute/second, millisecond. Also, the hour/minute/second column drops the first zero if its before noon.

```
print(stockdata['date_time'][0])
20120201 41206 300

print(stockdata['date_time'][50000])
20120201 151117 770
```

Ideally, I would like to define my own function that could be called by the converters argument in the read_csv function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a `csv` file that looks like this:

```
date,time,milliseconds,value
20120201,41206,300,1
20120201,151117,770,2
```

Then using `parse_dates`, `index_cols` and `date_parser` parameters of `read_csv` method, one could construct a `pandas` `DataFrame` with time index like this:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
parse = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=[['date', 'time', 'milliseconds']],
                 index_col=0, date_parser=parse)
```

This yields:

```
                            value
date_time_milliseconds           
2012-02-01 04:12:06.300000      1
2012-02-01 15:11:17.770000      2
```

And `df.index`:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-02-01 04:12:06.300000, 2012-02-01 15:11:17.770000]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

This answer is based on a similar solution [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615504/parse-dates-when-yyyymmdd-and-hh-are-in-separate-columns-using-pandas-in-python).

Comment: i guess the lack of zeroes doesn't screw up %H