# How do I combine date and time columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

As I am a new in python world I would like to ask some more experienced developers to help me combining these 2 columns please. SO I have DATE and time in one column.

I would normally add two of them data['Date'] + data['Time'] but date is not really recognized a column  and therefore I can not do it here.

Thanks for help guys!

[image]

Comment: `Date` is an index. Use `data.index + data.Time`

Comment: I think that [Reading data from csv into pandas when date and time are in separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17492923/15497888) might be easier to read in the date and time columns directly as a datetime. `data = pd.read_csv('sample_data/df.csv', parse_dates={'Datetime': ['Date', 'Time']}, index_col='Datetime')`